# mod_wsgi.so for windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

Where can I get `mod_wsgi.so` for windows 7 64 bit?

I have researched around and all point me to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

But there is **no** mod_wsgi.so

I found another link https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so

But I am not sure whether it can be trusted or not. Besides it seems that it is for 32 bit.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're not sure that a file published by the author of mod_wsgi can be trusted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you had read the Google Code page and [followed the link](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi) you would have found [this](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases/download/4.4.12/mod_wsgi-windows-4.4.12.tar.gz), which includes multiple versions including a 64-bit version built with VC10 for httpd 2.4.

Answer (score 4):

I have recently did this set up.. And believe me it was really difficult specially on windows machine...These two reference link helped me to achieve that..

1. https://beamtic.com/installing-mod-wsgi-apache-windows
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/RVD1hIxb2eI

In short:

1. Install Python 3.x
2. Download Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tool compatible to python version that you have been using.
3. Run this command -> mod_wsgi-express module-config
4. Once you run this command it will give you some output.  In my case it was:

   `LoadFile "f:/anaconda_3_32_bit/python37.dll"
   LoadModule wsgi_module "f:/anaconda_3_32_bit/lib/sitepackages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd"
   WSGIPythonHome "f:/anaconda_3_32_bit"`
5. Paste this configuration as it is in httpd.conf file, for apache web server.. Do not change anything at all

And you are done !! Hope it'll help someone :)

Comment: If you run the command "mod_wsgi-express module-config" it says "it is not recognised as internal command"!