# "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" after adding "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so"

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wampserver

I am trying to run python on wampserver, I am following [How to install Python with Wampserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266153/how-to-install-python-with-wampserver) as guide.

Setup Configuration:

Python 2.7.6(64-bit);  wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64bit; 
Windows 7 (64 bit)

For mod_wsgi: I tried all three 64 bit binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

But as I add "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so" line to load wsgi module in httpd.conf, the server fails with error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Any help on what am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like your server is not running.  What do the startup or error logs say?

Comment: Thanks covener. I fixed it. The problem was with the versions. I installed python3.3.3(64-bit); Because the mod_wsgi from the link were not supporting python 2.7.6(64-bit), it was not working.

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE SEND THE mod_wsgi file for python 3

Comment: Oh, it was way back in 2015 end. I have changed my laptop, projects and jobs since then. Try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979401/mod-wsgi-so-for-windows-7-64-bit . Let me know if you fixed it.